# How to use detect failure in command substitution

Tags: bash

As you know set -e is very useful to discover any failure when command is executed. However I found it to be delicate to use and I don't know how to use it in the following scenarios:

==============First example================================

```
set -e
function main() {    
  local X1="$(exp::notdefined)"    
  echo "Will reach here : ${LINENO}"    
  X2="$(exp::notdefined)"    
  echo "Will not reach here : ${LINENO}"
}
main
```

==============Second example================================

```
set -e    
function exp::tmp() {    
  echo "Now '$-' is "$-" : ${LINENO}"    
  false    
  return 0
}    
function main() {    
  X1="$(exp::tmp)"    
  echo "Will reach here : ${LINENO}. '\$X1' : ${X1}"    
  X2="$(set -e ; exp::tmp)"    
  echo "Will not reach here : ${LINENO}"
}    
main
```

===============================

The first example shows that, if we use command substitution on a local variable, then it will not fail even if the command substituted is not found. I don't know how to detect these kinds of failures.

The second example shows that, if the bash options (-e) will not propagate unless we call set -e inside the command braces. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: If David is right, you could split the `local` variable declaration & definition into two separate lines, to get the expected error code out of the second statement.

Answer (score 7):

You request immediate exit on pipeline failure with `-e`, e.g.:

```
-e      Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consistof a single simple
        command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above), 
        exits with a non-zero status.
```

The reason the bad *command substitution* does not cause failure within the function is because `local` provides its own *return status*.

> **local [option] [name[=value] ...]**
> ... The *return status* is `0` unless local is used outside a function, an
> invalid name is supplied, or name is a readonly variable.

The assignment of a failed command substitution *does not* cause `local` to return non-zero. Therefore, no immediate-exit is triggered.

As far as checking for a failure of command substitution following `local`, since the output is assigned to the variable, and the return will not be *non-zero* in the event of command substitution failure, you would have to validate by checking the variable contents itself for expected values for success/failure.

#### export semantics

For reference, it is worth mentioning that `export FOO=$(some_command)` has similar semantics:

> **export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...**
> **export -p**
> ... export returns an *exit status* of 0 unless an invalid option is encountered, one of the names is not a valid shell variable name, or `-f` is supplied with a name that is not a function.

Comment: I'm certain I saw a similar question that quoted this same manual section a few months ago, but now I can't find it.

Comment: Both came from *man bash*, from the `local` and `set` builtin sections. Around pages 530 and 690.

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything wrong with your answer, but I'd like to mark this as a duplicate of the earlier question.

Answer (score 1):

From the bash manual:

```
   Subshells spawned to execute command substitutions inherit the value of
   the -e option from the parent shell. When not in posix mode, bash
   clears the -e option in such subshells.
```

Example 2 behaves differently when bash runs with `--posix`; however for example 1 I can't find any documentation explaining why `local` would cause this.